# How to combine few videos in one on android

Tags: java, android, video

What is the best way to combine few videos in one clip for Android?

I need to concat few videos one to an other and make a long movie from them?

Any suggestions where to start?
Is there some kind of library or something that can help me out?

Tnx

Comment: Have you done a SO-Search on that? This question has been on here very often before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=combine+videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ffmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) for that. Of course, this is not a Java library, so you'd have to use the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). There are various ways to concatenate video files with ffmpeg, as described [here](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-join-video-files_003f):

> A few multimedia containers (MPEG-1, MPEG-2 PS, DV) allow to
>   concatenate video by merely concatenating the files them.
>
> Hence you may concatenate your multimedia files by first transcoding
>   them to these privileged formats, then using the humble cat command
>   (or the equally humble copy under Windows), and finally transcoding
>   back to your format of choice.
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i input1.avi -qscale:v 1 intermediate1.mpg
> ffmpeg -i input2.avi -qscale:v 1 intermediate2.mpg
> cat intermediate1.mpg intermediate2.mpg > intermediate_all.mpg
> ffmpeg -i intermediate_all.mpg -qscale:v 2 output.avi
> ```

The linked document also shows other ways to concatenate.

Comment: this gives me an error: 

Compile thumb  : ffmpeg <= ffmpeg.c
jni/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.c:22:20: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.o] Error 1    

I am using https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264 to get it working with android but no luck I get this error. I have downloaded with --recursive to get all files.

Comment: @Toshe Sorry I don't know what's going on there.

Comment: this is helpfull: https://github.com/churnlabs/android-ffmpeg-sample

this also: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-android-applications-based-on-ffmpeg-by-an-example/